# The $ Does Not Convert Text To Code What Should I Do?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, vue-cli-4

The $ Does Not Convert Text To Code What Should I Do?

```
if(this.rules.min && this.value.length < this.rules.min){
    return 'Minimum length is ${this.rules.min}'
  }
```

[image]

Comment: instead of '....' use backticks: `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bulent says you need to use **backticks quote** like that :

```js
if(this.rules.min && this.value.length < this.rules.min){
  return `Minimum length is ${this.rules.min}`
}
```

Comment: No problem, and you have a typo in you image `Requird` must be `Required` with a `ed`. Cancel my last, it seem to be valid also as it writen. So happy coding. :)